# How to create a program that reads nine integers into a 3x3 array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int test[2][3][2];
  printf("Enter nine values: \n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
      for (int k = 0; k < 1; ++k)
      {
        scanf("%d", &test[i][j][k]);
      }
    }
  }
  // Printing values with proper index.
  printf("\nDisplaying values:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
      for (int k = 0; k < 2; ++k)
      {
     printf("test[%d][%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, k, test[i][j][k]);
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Perhaps I am just doing this wrong but I am having trouble in understanding how to get my program to read only 9 integers an output a 3x3 array from the user. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your program?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems that you forgot to post your attempt into the question (your code).

Comment: If you want to work with a 3×3 array, why did you define an array with dimensions 2×3×2?

Comment: Thanks just realized that

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a 2D array (a matrix in other words), of dimension 3x3, so eventually what you need is something like this:

```
int arr[3][3];
```

which creates a 2D array with 3 rows and 3 columns. In your attempt, you used a 3 dimensional array, which is not what you want.

I think you will understand the rest (which you already know from what I see from your good attempt) from my example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 3
#define M 3

int main(void)
{
  int arr[N][M] = {0};

  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
      scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);

  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
      printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

See it also <kbd>[live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8fliGZeByii6GKNK)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You're not following the dimensions of your array at all. You have a 3-dimensional array here, dimensions 2 x 3 x 2. Assuming it gets filled with 0's, to help visualize:

```
[
  [
    [0, 0],
    [0, 0],
    [0, 0]
  ],
  [
    [0, 0],
    [0, 0],
    [0, 0]
  ]
]
```

Keep in mind an array is indexed `0` to `n-1`, where `n` is the size of the array.

Your first for-loop iterates to 2, which is equal to the size of your outermost array. That will result in a segmentation fault.

You should use a 2-dimensional array and `#define` your dimensions.